# Cocoa. Create NSTextView, add an NSString to it and print

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a window with a button for printing receipts. What I need to do is to create a simple NSTextView, add an NSString to it (at least something like "Hello World") and print it without displaying NSTextView on the window.

Here is what I currently have:

```
    NSTextView *textView = [[NSTextView alloc] init];

    NSString *text = @"testing";

    [textView setEditable:true];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange( 0, [[textView string] length]);
    [textView setSelectedRange:range];
    [[[textView textStorage] mutableString] appendString:text];

    NSPrintOperation *printOperation;

    printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:textView];


    [printOperation runOperation];
```

when I run it, I see printing dialog, but preview is empty. 
When I change printOperationWithView:textView]; from textView to one of the existing views on my window, it prints ok.

The main thing is.. I don't want to display the view after I click Print button. Ideally I would like to print the text, not the view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using `-initWithFrame` with a nonzero rect?

```
NSTextView *textview = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 468, 648);
```

(468 x 648 would make it fit an A4 sheet with 1-inch margins.)

Comment: A height of 648 produces 2 pages (in 10.7.3). Am I the only one?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation which works in an `NSDocument` subclass. Modify it to suit your needs.

```
- (NSPrintOperation *)printOperationWithSettings:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)printSettings error:(NSError * _Nullable __autoreleasing *)outError
{
    NSPrintInfo * printInfo = [self printInfo];

    printInfo.topMargin = 15.0;
    printInfo.leftMargin = 10.0;
    printInfo.rightMargin = 10.0;
    printInfo.bottomMargin = 15.0;
    printInfo.verticallyCentered = NO;

    NSRect bounds = printInfo.imageablePageBounds;

    NSTextView * printView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    printView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;

    [printView.textStorage appendAttributedString:self.attributedStringRepresentation];

    return [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:printView printInfo:printInfo];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just:

```
[textView print];
```

Comment: yes, I did. I tried  `[textView print:nil];`  `[textView print:self];`  it still returns nothing.  One more thing: If I add something like     `NSRect pos;
        pos.origin = NSMakePoint(0,0);
        NSTextView *textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:pos];` it displays 21 blank pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is very good.  Just one more enhancement.  In order for the print out not to be centered, and to fill up the page correctly, pass printInfo in as a parameter.

```
NSPrintOperation *printOperation;

NSPrintInfo *pInfo = [[NSPrintInfo alloc] init];
[pInfo setBottomMargin:50];
[pInfo setTopMargin:50];
[pInfo setVerticallyCentered:false];
printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:textView printInfo:pInfo];

[printOperation runOperation];
```