# Print text in MonoMac/Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, printing, monomac

I have a MonoMac application that I wish to print from. Currently I have the following code:

```
private void PrintText(text)
{
    NSTextView nsTextView = new NSTextView();
    nsTextView.Font = NSFont.LabelFontOfSize(12);
    nsTextView.TextColor = NSColor.Black;
    nsTextView.TextStorage.Append(new NSAttributedString(text));

    NSPrintOperation nsPrintOperation = GetPrintOperation(nsTextView); // Creates a NSPrintOperation and NSPrintInfo as well as set my default settings
    nsTextView.Bounds.Width = nsPrintOperation.PrintInfo.PaperSize.Width;
    nsTextView.Bounds.Height = float.MaxValue;
    nsPrintOperation.RunOperation();
}
```

Sadly while I do get a print dialog it will print a blank page. Any ideas what I'm going wrong?

Comment: You might be able to find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097219/cocoa-create-nstextview-add-an-nsstring-to-it-and-print